# Coq: induction principles for void, unit and bool from nat and fin

Tags: coq

I can define finite types in Coq like this:

```
Inductive fin : nat -> Set :=
| FZ : forall {n}, fin (S n)
| FS : forall {n}, fin n -> fin (S n).

Definition void := fin 0.

Definition unit := fin 1.
Definition vunit : unit := FZ.

Definition bool := fin 2.
Definition true : bool := FZ.
Definition false : bool := FS FZ.
```

Can I proof the induction principles for `void`, `unit` and `bool` just from the induction principles of `nat` and `fin`?

I have proven the induction principle for `void` already:

```
Lemma void_ind : forall (P : void -> Prop) (x : void), P x.
Proof.
  intros.
  inversion x.
Qed.
```

But I don't know how to proceed with `unit`:

```
Lemma unit_ind : forall (P : unit -> Prop) (x : unit), P vunit -> P x.
```

I figure I need:

```
Lemma unit_uniq : forall (x : fin 1), x = FZ.
```

And in my head this seems obvious, but I don't know how to proceed with the proof.

After that I also like to prove:

```
Lemma bool_ind : forall (P : bool -> Prop) (x : bool), P true -> P false -> P x.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways of deriving these induction principles.  Since you asked
explicitly about using the induction principles for `fin` and `nat`, I am going
to use those.  Actually, since all the derived types are finite, we can get away
with just using a case analysis principle, which we can define in terms of
induction.  Here is how we define case analysis for the natural numbers. (I am
putting the `Type` valued recursor here, since we'll need the extra generality.)

```
Definition nat_case :
  forall (P : nat -> Type),
    P 0 ->
    (forall n, P (S n)) ->
    forall n, P n :=
  fun P HZ HS => nat_rect P HZ (fun n _ => HS n).
```

We can define an analogous principle for `fin`.  But to make it more useful, we
add a little twist.  The original recursor for `fin` is parameterized over a
predicate `P : forall n, fin n -> Prop` that must work for `fin`s of an
arbitrary upper bound.  We'll use `nat_case` so that we can fix the upper bound
we use (cf. the types of `P` below).

```
Inductive fin : nat -> Set :=
| FZ : forall {n}, fin (S n)
| FS : forall {n}, fin n -> fin (S n).

Definition fin_case_result n : fin n -> Type :=
  nat_case (fun n => fin n -> Type)
           (fun x : fin 0 =>
              forall (P : fin 0 -> Type), P x)
           (fun m (x : fin (S m)) =>
              forall (P : fin (S m) -> Type),
                P FZ ->
                (forall y, P (FS y)) ->
                P x)
           n.

Definition fin_case :
  forall n (x : fin n), fin_case_result n x :=
  fun n x =>
    fin_rect fin_case_result
             ( (* FZ case *)
               fun m P HZ HS => HZ)
             ( (* FS case.
                  The blank is the result of the recursive call. *)
               fun m (y : fin m) _ P HZ HS => HS y)
             n x.
```

Thanks to `fin_case`, we can define the induction principles you wanted:

```
Definition void := fin 0.
Definition unit := fin 1.
Definition vunit : unit := FZ.

Definition bool := fin 2.
Definition true : bool := FZ.
Definition false : bool := FS FZ.

Definition void_ind :
  forall (P : void -> Prop)
         (x : void),
    P x :=
  fun P x => fin_case 0 x P.

Definition unit_ind :
  forall (P : unit -> Prop)
         (HZ : P vunit)
         (x : unit),
    P x :=
  fun P HZ x =>
    fin_case 1 x P HZ (void_ind (fun y => P (FS y))).

Definition bool_ind :
  forall (P : bool -> Prop)
         (HT : P true)
         (HF : P false)
         (x : bool),
    P x :=
  fun P HT HF x =>
    fin_case 2 x P HT (unit_ind (fun y => P (FS y)) HF).
```

Comment: This is great, thanks! I wanted to define a type theory with no datatypes but just nat, fin and a fixpoint operator, with these definitions I'll be able to derive induction for datatypes defined from those core elements!